# Best way to implement lookup tables in Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, translation, powerquery, lookup-tables

I have a table of country values as in:

```
SourceCode       TranslationCode
United States    USA
US               USA
Great Britain    GBR
England          GBR
```

```
Source Customer Table
CustNbr     CustName      Country
12345       Acme Tools    United States
23456       Smith and Co  US
34567       Rogers Assoc  Great Britain
```

```
--Expected Result--
CustNbr     CustName      Country
12345       Acme Tools    USA
23456       Smith and Co  USA
34567       Rogers Assoc  GBR
```

In Power Query, what's the best way to handle this so that I can refer to the lookup table dynamically?
The end user may have values to add to the lookup/translation table(s) and expect those to be included/replaced the next time the process is executed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query you'd typically do a merge instead of a lookup. The lookup table can be a data source that user can update.

- Load the lookup table as a new query with all columns. Save this as a connection only, so you don't duplicate the data.
- In your main query, merge the lookup query and join on the columns with the matching values, i.e. `Country` from the main query and `TranslationCode` from the lookup query, with "All items from first, matching from second".
- Expand the `TranslationCode` from the joined query
- delete the original `Country` column
- rename columns to your preferences.